# Curved image path when scrolling page

Tags: javascript, bezier, curve

I'm trying to create a rollercoaster ride for a project and need the rollercoaster to follow a path.

You can see my illustration on [rollercoaster](http://www.graahf.dk/rollercoaster/rollercoaster.html)

I need the red box to follow the rollercoaster road in the background? The red box illustreres the image I'm going to use. Is this possible? I'm trying using this code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            //var windowHeight = $(window).height();
            var windowHeight = $('.road2').height();
            //var S = scrollTop + Math.floor(windowHeight / 2);

            var S = $(this).scrollTop();            // scrolled distance
            var t = 0 + (S/windowHeight);                
            //var T = 0 + (S/36);                        // value for Top
            //var L = 300 + Math.abs(Math.sin(S/400)*460);  // value for Left
            //
            //$(".rollerImage").css({top: T+'%', left: L+'px'});    //set CSS

            var canvas_X=400;
            var canvas_Y=400;

            // Increment Parameterization
            t += 0.05;

            // Width of Car
            var car_X=150;
            // Hieght of Car
            var car_Y=50;

            // Point A
            var a_X=0;
            var a_Y=0;

            // Point B
            var b_X=canvas_X-car_X; //Place point B at the end
            var b_Y=0;

            // Center of Semi Circle
            var c_X=(b_X-a_X)/2;
            var c_Y=(a_Y-a_Y)/2;

            // Calculate X and Y point on trajectory 
            var x = a_X + t * (b_X- a_X);
            var y = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((b_X - a_X),2)/4 + Math.pow((x-c_X),2));

            $(".rollerImage").css({top: x+'px', left: y+'px'});    //set CSS

        });            
    </script>
```

Hope someone can help with this type of path animation. Maybe it is possible to define the path in a array of coordinates?

I've tried using [joel scrollpath](http://joelb.me/scrollpath/), but can't "bind" an image to the path :(

//Graahf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to get it working with the jQuery Scrollpath using your html and css files plus the code from the demo site.

Check if this is OK for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Skr4R/6/embedded/result/

You can also check the sources of the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Skr4R/6/

Important for this, is that the entire wrapper moves and rotates, that is why in my solution the train-image is outside of the wrapper, like this:

```
<div class="rollerCoasters">
  <img src="" style="background:red; height:100px; width:50px; position:absolute; top:380px; left:50%; z-index:200; margin-left:-25px">
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="road1"><img src="base64-encoded-img" width="1434" height="539"/></div>
</div>
```

Hope this gets you started. It might not be the best solution, if you want the train to move, and not it's surroundings.

Comment: Nice :) It works and helps me on, but what if I want the train to move / rotate when the wrapper background makes a curve?

Plus the train is going to be larger :)

Comment: The problem is now that when you resize the browser window, the road moves up beneath the train... :/

Comment: In the stylesheet, adjust the styles of `.rollerImage` to `top: 50%;` and `margin: -90px 0 0 -70px;` instead of margin-left. The code of the answer was a bit sloppy, just to get you started quickly ;)
If you look at [Joeys Scrollpath Democode](http://joelb.me/scrollpath/script/demo.js) you'll also notice, he used `.rotate` to rotate the screen around the train. Some documentation for this is [here](https://github.com/JoelBesada/scrollpath#rotate-radians-options)

Comment: Aaah I saw that, thanks for position :) The problem with the .rotate is that it rotates the wrapper/path and not the train... :) But thanks anyway :)

Comment: I've made it with 2 functions. One with the first trackand one with the second track. My problem i now, that when I add a third track, it lays on top of the second track. I need it to always be below all the other tracks, so if I have 3 tracks, the fourth wil be at the bottom and so on.

Answer (score 0):

i am trying to achieve the same process and this has helped me along, the way forward about roating the train/object with the track could you not rotate the background(track to make the train look like it is following the track)

Comment: I'm trying to make a smooth rotation with the track, so it looks like the train is ride it :)

Comment: i had a little play with the js fiddle and came u with http://jsfiddle.net/PLJVc/1/embedded/result/

Comment: Got an idea how to make it rotate in IE8? ;)

Comment: Damn :) What if I only want to rotate the train and not the surroundings?